# Azure VPN setup in Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I'm trying to configure VPN setup in the Azure portal which is connecting an 
On-Premises server from Service Fabric cluster. I have followed the below article to achieve the task.

[Create a Site-to-Site connection in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal)

On-Premises VPN Peering IP: 106.62.121.242 (Sample IP) 
Azure VPN Peering IP: 105.50.59.124 (Sample IP)

On-Premises - Hosts Using VPN (Encryption Domain): 106.62.127.196 (Sample IP) 
Azure - Hosts Using VPN (Service Fabric Load balancer IP): 62.166.19.229 (Sample IP)

After I have configured the pre-shared key I can see that the connection has been established successfully. But the traffic is not going from Azure Service Fabric VM. I'm getting the following error when I tried to check the traffic from one of the Service Fabric VM.

PS C:> Test-NetConnection -Port 443 devapi.example.com 
WARNING: TCP connect to devapi.example.com:443 failed 
WARNING: Ping to devapi.example.com failed -- Status: TimedOut

ComputerName           : devapi.example.com 
RemoteAddress          : 106.62.127.196 (sample IP) 
RemotePort             : 443 
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet 2 
SourceAddress          : 10.0.0.4 
PingSucceeded          : False 
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms 
TcpTestSucceeded       : False

I have been told that the SourceAddress should be the Service Fabric Load balancer IP to send and receive traffic. Please help.

Comment: `devapi.example.com` this api app is on Azure Service Fabric cluster
? It seems that it provides service to Public Internet. When you create a VPN connection, you could access Azure with private IP, but the traffic that goes to Internet also will transfer on the Internet, not Azure Vnet.

Comment: No, devapi.example.com service is on On-Premises server. What would be the solution to resolve the issue? Please explain the steps which I need to follow to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you ping your on-premise server with private IP?

Comment: I couldn't. I'm getting Request timeout message.

Comment: I suggest you could check VPN log refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-troubleshoot-manage-portal).

Comment: If you have some error log, please post here. Maybe we could help you.

Comment: I have downloaded the log from the Storage. I can see only two files in the Zip ConnectionStats.txt and CPUStat.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151347/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-sarva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure - Hosts Using VPN (Service Fabric Load balancer IP):
>   62.166.19.229 (Sample IP)

This is wrong. You should configure Azure Virtual Network ip range, such as `10.0.0.0/16`. The value is not Azure Load Balancer Public IP address.

Note: You need change it on Azure Gateway and your local VPN gateway.